# Why is the notation for irrational number not mainstream?

Tags: soft-question, notation

In everywhere you see the symbol for the set of rational number as $\mathbb{Q}$

However, to find actual symbol to denote the set of irrational number is difficult. Most people usually denote it as $\Bbb{R}\backslash\Bbb{Q}$

But recently I saw someone using $\mathbb{I}$ to denote irrational numbers. I like it and wish for it to be more mainstream.

Will $\mathbb{I}$ ever catch on?

Comment: Because the irrational numbers are an anomaly in some sense, $\Bbb Q$ is a nice small field, and $\Bbb R$ is its completion, so the irrationals, $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ are just what you need to add to the rationals to make them complete. In other sense, the irrationals are like the imaginary numbers, in the sense that they're not closed under the fundamental arithmetical operations, and that makes them rather algebraicly boring.

Comment: In some circles $\Bbb P$ is fairly common; I’ve seen it more often than I’ve seen $\Bbb I$, which has the disadvantage of also being used occasionally for $[0,1]$. And in contexts in which the irrationals actually *are* a very natural object, they’re likely to be denoted by $\omega^\omega$, $\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$, ${^\omega\omega}$, or ${^{\Bbb N}\Bbb N}$, since those notations give useful structural information.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Hmm, interesting... $\mathbb P$?  Do you know if it's just because  $\Bbb P-\Bbb Q-\Bbb R$ or if it's because of something linguistic?

Comment: Same reason there's no word for all fruits that aren't bananas. It's just not that useful to point to.

Comment: @rschwieb: My guess is that it’s simply from the alphabetic sequence, but I don’t actually know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strictly speaking "will this notation I like ever catch on?" Is inappropriate for this site. But we can still weigh the pros and cons of the suggestion and mention any variants we know.

Cons:

1. Introduces yet another symbol to memorize
2. weak improvement over the obvious alternative
3. Rarely do you talk enough about irrationals collectively  to warrant special notation
4. Already sometimes used for idealizers in ring theory.
5. Similar to notation for the unit interval that I've seen.
6. Breaks a pattern of using blackboard bold for familiar sets with algebraic structure

Pros:
1. You write one symbol instead of two with a backslash

So basically I think you're finding yourself in the position of the guy on Shark Tank pitching the product that solves a problem nobody has.

Variants: 
None I've seen.